# how to use gif image as splash screen?

Tags: php, bootstrapping, animated-gif

I am using a gif image to make a splash screen but the problem is it loads only one time. whenever i refresh the page gif image doesn't work.Kindly help.

```
     </STYLE>
  <body style="background:black;" id="page-top">
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("window.location='http://example.com'",2000);
 </script>
  <div style="   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;">
<img src="img/logo.gif" onload="displayImage(this)" style="height:
400px;"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function displayImage(obj) {
obj.style.display = "block";
}</script>
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: that gif  image loads only one time @Chris

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with the file itself. In Photoshop, go to File -> Save for Web & Devices -> Looping options and select Forever and try again.